# Adding folder pointers to default .sublime-build files (Sublime Text 3, c++)

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, header-files, build-system, sublime-build

I am looking for a straight-forward way to add folder pointers in Sublime Text 3 when I am using it's built-in C++ compiler, `C++ Single File` Build System. I have written custom `.sublime-build` files before, but I also cannot find the default file `C++ Single File` .sublime-build file -- if I could do that, I could simply add an "-I /usr/..." to include additional folders.

As a solution, I am looking for:

1. Use the same .sublime-build that is used in the default `C++ Single File` Build System, while
2. Adding additional folders to point to. These additional folders would include header files (ex. armadillo.h)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is use the `PackageControl` under `Preferences`, and install `PackageResourceViewer`.  Once installed, you can use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` > type `prv` > click `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` > `C++` > `C++ Single File.sublime-build`. Copy this code into a new `.sublime-build` file, and add the additional folder(s) using `"-I C:/path/to/folder"